# Native PHP functions that allow double-dot range syntax

Tags: php, string, function, range

Some native PHP string functions have a parameter which is a string of one or more unordered characters (also referred to as a "character mask").  In some cases,  character ranges can be expressed using double-dot syntax.

For example: `echo trim('foo24', '0..9');` prints `foo` because `2` and `4` fall within the `0` through `9` range.

What are the other native PHP string functions with the same feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Native PHP string functions that respect double-dot range expressions:

- `addcslashes()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9FG4Y))

  ```
   echo addcslashes('adobe', 'a..e');
   // \a\do\b\e
  ```
- `chop()` -- alias of `rtrim()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9lAAP))

  ```
   echo chop('adobe', 'a..e');
   // ado
  ```
- `ltrim()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uOnK0))

  ```
   echo ltrim('adobe', 'a..e');
   // obe
  ```
- `rtrim()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uOnK0))

  ```
   echo rtrim('adobe', 'a..e');
   // ado
  ```
- `str_word_count()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aK9P5))

  ```
   var_export(
       str_word_count('do not break|on|pipe', 1, '{..}')
   );
   // ['do', 'not', 'break|on|pipe']
  ```
- `trim()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PHg17))

  ```
   echo trim('adobe', 'a..e');
   // o
  ```
- `ucwords()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RYC7b))

  ```
   echo ucwords('backdoorman', 'a..e');
   // BaCkdOormaN
  ```

---

Here are some native functions where ranged expressions are not expanded, but might be reasonable candidates for the feature:

- `strcspn()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/t9RCI)) (expansion would be reasonable)

  ```
   echo strcspn('cdplayer', 'b..e');
   // 6
   // 0 if range enabled
  ```
- `strpbrk()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4a3QC)) (expansion would be reasonable)

  ```
   echo strpbrk('stackoverflow', 'b..f');
   // flow
   // ckoverflow if range enabled
  ```
- `strspn()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CocP2)) (expansion would be reasonable)

  ```
   echo strspn('adobe', 'a..e');
   // 1
   // 2 if range enabled
  ```
- `strtok()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GnM1T)) (expansion would be reasonable)

  ```
   echo strtok('toddler', 'a..e');
   // toddl
   // to if range enabled
  ```
- `strtr()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rjh0A)) (out of topic scope because not technically a character mask -- character order matters)

  ```
   echo strtr('adobe', 'a..e', 'A..E');
   // AdobE
   // ADoBE if range enabled
  ```

---

Due to technical challenges of supporting `..` syntax with multibyte characters, the following native functions will not allow `..` 
Ref: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mb_trim

- `mb_ltrim()`
- `mb_rtrim()`
- `mb_trim()`